# Vulkan no VK_KHR_ray_tracing extension

Tags: vulkan

When I list the device extensions using the shipped tool 'vulkaninfoSDK.exe' in Vulkan SDK, it cannot find the 'VK_KHR_ray_tracing' device extension. Instead, it only finds the 'VK_NV_ray_tracing'. Any idea of how to make it available?

My graphics card is an RTX 2080 Ti and a GTX 980 Ti. RTX 2080 Ti is set to the primary GPU. My Windows OS has been updated to the latest build 19041.508. The Vulkan SDK version is 1.2.148.1 and the Nivida driver version is 452.06. Both should be the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `VK_KHR_ray_tracing` extension is not yet finalized, and therefore only exposed by the Vulkan Developer drivers available at https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver. Support for the main driver line will probably be added after the extension has left the beta phase.

Comment: Will 'VK_KHR_ray_tracing' finally be the substitution of 'VK_NV_ray_tracing' in the future?

Comment: Yes, the KHR extension will be a cross-vendor version that will supersede  the NV one.